# Compute $\int_{0}^x \vert \sin(t)\vert dt$ for $x\in \mathbb{R^+}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $x\in \mathbb{R^+}$,
>   compute $$\int_{0}^x \vert \sin(t)\vert dt$$

I tried like this :
$$
\int_{0}^x \vert \sin(t)\vert dt=\int_0^{\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi}\rfloor \pi}\vert \sin(t)\vert dt+\int_{\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi}\rfloor \pi}^x\vert \sin(t)\vert dt
$$

But I don't see how can I continue.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: for the first part, it is equal to $\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \rfloor \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin (t) dt$, which you can compute. The second one is equal to $\int_{0}^{x-\pi \lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \rfloor}\sin (t) dt$.

As pointed out in comments, we can argue like this since we are looking at $|\sin|$. Morally, $\int_0^{\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi}\rfloor \pi}\vert sin(t)\vert dt$
counts how many complete periods of $|\sin|$ we have (i.e. a semi-period of $\sin$, where it is positive), that's why this reduction is allowed. The second part, $\int_{\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi}\rfloor \pi}^x\vert sin(t)\vert dt$, can be shifted to $[0,x-\pi \lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \rfloor ]$ since there $\sin$ is positive.

Comment: I don't understand the second one , what did you mean by can be shifted ?

Comment: $\sin$ is a periodic function with period $2 \pi$, hence you have $\int_{a}^{b}\sin (t)dt= \int_{a + 2k \pi}^{b + 2k \pi} \sin (t)dt$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Analogously $|\sin|$ is a periodic function with period $\pi$, hence you have $\int_{a}^{b}\sin (t)dt= \int_{a + k \pi}^{b + k \pi} \sin (t)dt$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So we can shift everything by $\pi \lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \rfloor$. Now we are on $[0,x-\pi \lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \rfloor ]$. In particular $x-\pi \lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \rfloor < \pi$, hence there $\sin = |\sin|$ and we can conclude.

Comment: @Stefano I see! Thanks a lot.